# Clear a single notification with PushPlugin for Cordova in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-pushplugin

In an iOS app that I developed with Cordova I'm using the [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin), I'm facing a problem (maybe it's not be a problem for other people) that when you have multiple notifications of the app in the notifications center if you click one (the app starts) of them, then you take a look at your notification center again and you won't see any remaining notification.

I took a look at the plugin code and I found that in the function applicationDidBecomeActive of the file AppDelegate+notification.m contains this line:

```
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

Could be this line the problem? If not, how I can edit the code to only clear the clicked notification?

I opened an issue in the plugin repository days ago but I did not received any response from the developer/s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how iOS 7 and previous versions manage the notifications, there is no way to delete just one notification, you can delete all or none, but not one, it's not a plugin bug and there is nothing you can do

it seems that on iOS 8 apple automatically removes the notification when you click it, so you just don't have to execute this line on iOS 8: `application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;`

You can use this Preprocessor Macro

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
```

and check the version to remove all the notifications if the device have a previous version

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"8.0")) {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think so, please, check the Skype app or many others, this app does exactly what I want.

Comment: see my edit, iOS 8 deletes them automatically when you tap them